# Does Angular add any css class/directive for disabled controls in Reactive forms?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am disabling some controls in the reactive form dynamically based on certain conditions. I also want to provide specific styling to those disabled controls. Does Angular add any css class or any directive to the disabled controls? I didn't find any. How do I change the styles of the disabled controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target disabled element using :disabled **[CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled)**

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" class="name" [formControl]="control">
```

**component.css**

```
.name:disabled {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  color: linen;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lhzoqq?file=src/global_styles.css)**